# Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server

Tags: gui, ubuntu

Im having problems installing SOAPUI on my Ubuntu 12.04.
It throws:
"Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server"

My java version is:
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

so i think this is not the problem..
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very late reply, but I wasted a lot of time trying to sort this, so I hope someone else will find it useful.

The bundled JRE is a 32-bit version, and it has a dependency on libXtst. On my 64-bit Fedora box, installing the following package fixed it:

```
# yum install libXtst-1.2.0-3.fc17.i686
```

Make sure to install the **32-bit** version of libXtst (the .i686 in the end).

Answer (score 0):

> so i think this is not the problem..

Why? Because you have Java installed? X11 is something entirely different. Please provide a bit more information, like is this running on your local desktop, or a remote machine. Do you have X11 running? Output of xdpyinfo, etc.

Comment: no, i thought that because i have read that this problem might happend if you doesnt have installed in your machine the oracle java..
Im running it on my local desktop.
The xdpyinfo output is: (and goes on..)
name of display:    :0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11103000
X.Org version: 1.11.3
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7

Comment: @user1683628: Now the next question: Do you start SOAPUI under your user session, or as a different user, in a different session (i.e. through su, sudo)?

Comment: yes i runned the instaler with sudo.
also i could install it with -c option, but then SoapUI doesnt run, so maybee is because could not display the gui also

Comment: There's your problem: sudo doesn't hand over the X authentication token, programs started there won't be able to open a connection to the X server. The authentication token usually resides at `${HOME}/.Xauthrority`. E.g. it may be /home/foobar/.Xauthority. So open a sudo *shell* (`sudo -s`), then therein add the right authority environment (`export XAUTHORITY=/home/foobar/.Xauthority`), now you should be able to run the installer from within that shell. You must replace /home/foobar with your own home directory of course.

Comment: had no luck with this, the XAUTHORITY is now linked to my user, but still cant display the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've downloaded `SoapUI-x64-5.0.0.sh` (64-bit version) installer.

I've had the same issue when trying to run `SoapUI-x32-5.0.0.sh` (32-bit version) on x64 Ubuntu by mistake.